# How to show only Standard Format post in my custom taxonomy page -wordpress 3.8.1

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I want to show only standard format in my custom taxonomy:

Actually I have many category and format in my project , hence on this page I need only to show standard format and specific  category

---

```
<?php
/**
 * Locations taxonomy archive
 */
get_header();
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="primary-content">
        <h1 class="archive-title"><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $term->name ); ?> News</h1>

        <?php if ( !empty( $term->description ) ): ?>
        <div class="archive-description">
            <?php echo esc_html($term->description); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post clearfix'); ?>>
            <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <div class="content clearfix">
                <div class="post-info">
                    <p><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></p>
                </div><!--// end .post-info -->
                <div class="entry">
                    <?php the_content( __('Full story…') ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--// end #post-XX -->

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="navigation clearfix">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('« Previous Entries') ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Next Entries »') ?></div>
        </div>

        <?php else: ?>

        <h2 class="post-title">No News in <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $term->name ); ?></h2>
        <div class="content clearfix">
            <div class="entry">
                <p>It seems there isn't anything happening in <strong><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $term->name ); ?></strong> right now. Check back later, something is bound to happen soon.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!--// end .primary-content -->

    <div class="secondary-content">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div><!--// end .secondary-content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

tandard is not actually a post format. When no specific format is set, wordpress will assign Standard to that post. This is what you will see in the back end in post editor. If you need to exclude all other post types and just display something specific that has no post format assigned to it you will use `false == has_post_format()` For example

```
 if ( false == has_post_format()) {
    <--show post without a post format-->
   }
```

Comment: i tried above if condition but still its showing , photo , video format in above loop

Comment: any other solution ,  i have  cat=1,2 which are photos, and video resp. can i exclude this from above loop , so that i will see all post category .. except photo and video category post

Comment: Just to be clear, videos and photos are actually categories and not custom post types?

Comment: hi, i have not use any custom post , just using custom taxonomy(i:e motion) ,  and above code-loop  calls all post with include all category post, but i don't want photo,video category post to be  include in above loop...